# How to get data from read only field to a new input text field using valuechangelistner?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

My requirement is, once I input a value in a input text field, valuechangelistner will call & data will be populated in the next read only fields & then also for the below two input text data should be populated.

I am using a query based VO for this.

[image]

When I entered Employee number, Employee Number also populated in the below input text, but I want Level also populated in the below input text of Level.

```
<af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1">
        <af:spacer width="40" height="20" id="s5"/>
    <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl2" layout="horizontal">
      <af:button text="Back to Search Page" id="b1" action="backCompEmptoSearch"/>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
    <!--<af:inputText value="#{bindings.EmployeeNumber.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.EmployeeNumber.hints.label}"
                required="#{bindings.EmployeeNumber.hints.mandatory}"
                columns="#{bindings.EmployeeNumber.hints.displayWidth}"
                maximumLength="#{bindings.EmployeeNumber.hints.precision}" 
                shortDesc="#{bindings.EmployeeNumber.hints.tooltip}" id="it1"
                  valueChangeListener="#{CompBean.emphdrVCL}" autoSubmit="true">
    <f:validator binding="#{bindings.EmployeeNumber.validator}"/>
    <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.EmployeeNumber.format}"/>
  </af:inputText>-->
    <af:inputText label="EmployeeNumber" id="it9"  valueChangeListener="#{CompBean.emphdrVCL}" autoSubmit="true"/> 
    <af:spacer width="40" height="60" id="s3"/>
  <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1" partialTriggers="it9" rows="2">
    <af:inputText value="#{bindings.EmployeeName.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.EmployeeName.hints.label}"
                  required="#{bindings.EmployeeName.hints.mandatory}" readOnly="true"
                  columns="#{bindings.EmployeeName.hints.displayWidth}"
                  maximumLength="#{bindings.EmployeeName.hints.precision}"
                  shortDesc="#{bindings.EmployeeName.hints.tooltip}" id="it2">
      <f:validator binding="#{bindings.EmployeeName.validator}"/>
    </af:inputText>
    <af:inputText value="#{bindings.ServiceLine.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.ServiceLine.hints.label}"
                  required="#{bindings.ServiceLine.hints.mandatory}" readOnly="true"
                  columns="#{bindings.ServiceLine.hints.displayWidth}"
                  maximumLength="#{bindings.ServiceLine.hints.precision}"
                  shortDesc="#{bindings.ServiceLine.hints.tooltip}" id="it3">
      <f:validator binding="#{bindings.ServiceLine.validator}"/>
      <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.ServiceLine.format}"/>
    </af:inputText>
    <af:inputText value="#{bindings.EmployeeType.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.EmployeeType.hints.label}"
                  required="#{bindings.EmployeeType.hints.mandatory}" readOnly="true"
                  columns="#{bindings.EmployeeType.hints.displayWidth}"
                  maximumLength="#{bindings.EmployeeType.hints.precision}"
                  shortDesc="#{bindings.EmployeeType.hints.tooltip}" id="it4">
      <f:validator binding="#{bindings.EmployeeType.validator}"/>
    </af:inputText>

    <af:inputText value="#{bindings.LevelId.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.LevelId.hints.label}" 
                  required="#{bindings.LevelId.hints.mandatory}" readOnly="true"
                  columns="#{bindings.LevelId.hints.displayWidth}" maximumLength="#{bindings.LevelId.hints.precision}"
                  shortDesc="#{bindings.LevelId.hints.tooltip}" id="it6" autoSubmit="true"
                  valueChangeListener="#{CompBean.TestVcl}">
      <f:validator binding="#{bindings.LevelId.validator}"/>
    </af:inputText>
    <af:inputText value="#{bindings.CountryId.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.CountryId.hints.label}"
                  required="#{bindings.CountryId.hints.mandatory}" readOnly="true"
                  columns="#{bindings.CountryId.hints.displayWidth}"
                  maximumLength="#{bindings.CountryId.hints.precision}" shortDesc="#{bindings.CountryId.hints.tooltip}"
                  id="it7">
      <f:validator binding="#{bindings.CountryId.validator}"/>
    </af:inputText>
    <af:inputText value="#{bindings.TownOrCity.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.TownOrCity.hints.label}"
                  required="#{bindings.TownOrCity.hints.mandatory}" readOnly="true"
                  columns="#{bindings.TownOrCity.hints.displayWidth}"
                  maximumLength="#{bindings.TownOrCity.hints.precision}"
                  shortDesc="#{bindings.TownOrCity.hints.tooltip}" id="it8">
      <f:validator binding="#{bindings.TownOrCity.validator}"/>
    </af:inputText>
      <af:inputText value="#{bindings.EffectiveStartDate.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.EffectiveStartDate.hints.label}"
                    required="#{bindings.EffectiveStartDate.hints.mandatory}"
                    columns="#{bindings.EffectiveStartDate.hints.displayWidth}"
                    maximumLength="#{bindings.EffectiveStartDate.hints.precision}"
                    shortDesc="#{bindings.EffectiveStartDate.hints.tooltip}" id="it5">
        <f:validator binding="#{bindings.EffectiveStartDate.validator}"/>
        <af:convertDateTime pattern="#{bindings.EffectiveStartDate.format}"/>
      </af:inputText>
      <af:inputText value="#{bindings.EffectiveEndDate.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.EffectiveEndDate.hints.label}"
                    required="#{bindings.EffectiveEndDate.hints.mandatory}"
                    columns="#{bindings.EffectiveEndDate.hints.displayWidth}"
                    maximumLength="#{bindings.EffectiveEndDate.hints.precision}"
                    shortDesc="#{bindings.EffectiveEndDate.hints.tooltip}" id="it10">
        <f:validator binding="#{bindings.EffectiveEndDate.validator}"/>
        <af:convertDateTime pattern="#{bindings.EffectiveEndDate.format}"/>
      </af:inputText>
      <af:inputText value="#{bindings.Ctc.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.Ctc.hints.label}"
                    required="#{bindings.Ctc.hints.mandatory}" columns="#{bindings.Ctc.hints.displayWidth}"
                    maximumLength="#{bindings.Ctc.hints.precision}" shortDesc="#{bindings.Ctc.hints.tooltip}" id="it17">
        <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Ctc.validator}"/>
        <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.Ctc.format}"/>
      </af:inputText>
    </af:panelFormLayout>
  <af:spacer width="40" height="40" id="s40"/>
  <!--<af:inputText value="#{bindings.Ctc.inputValue}" label="#{bindings.Ctc.hints.label}" 
                required="#{bindings.Ctc.hints.mandatory}" columns="#{bindings.Ctc.hints.displayWidth}"
                maximumLength="#{bindings.Ctc.hints.precision}" shortDesc="#{bindings.Ctc.hints.tooltip}" id="it5">
    <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Ctc.validator}"/>
    <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern="#{bindings.Ctc.format}"/>
  </af:inputText>-->
  <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl2">

    <af:inputText label="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" id="it11"  binding="#{CompBean.propertyEmpno}" partialTriggers="it9"/>
    <af:inputText label="CTC" id="it1"   binding="#{CompBean.propertyCtc}"/>
      <af:inputText label="Level" id="it18" binding="#{CompBean.propertyLevel}" partialTriggers="it6"/> 
      <!--<af:inputDate label="EFFECTIVE_START_DATE" id="id1" binding="#{CompBean.propertyEfdate}"/>

    <af:inputDate label="EFFECTIVE_END_DATE" id="id2" binding="#{CompBean.propertyEdDate}"/>-->

    </af:panelFormLayout>
```

Jedeveloper 12.1.3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

on emphdrVCL method,
You are querying for the VO using employee number which yo got from the user input.

after exeuting the VO, fetch the current row and get attribte value for Ctc and LevelId and set the value for propertyLevel, propertyEdDate